# Encrypting small messages

Tags: encryption, e-commerce, rsa

i need to implement a coupon-code feature. because of the number of codes required and some other constraints, i can't store them in a database. in addition the displayed codes need to be short (around 10 characters).

my original idea was to use a cryptographic function to create codes by encrypting an ongoing counter. but i'm at a loss what method to use.

Because of the counter i would be encoding only a couple of bytes and I am aware that many algorithms are not secure when used with very short messages.

Is my Approach a good idea?
What algorithm could i use?

Comment: if you're terribly concerned with security and prevention of fraud, you really ought to send unique codes that you can validate belongs to a particular user account when they try to use it. The total amount of entropy in a 10 character code has a finite limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, and as per my comment, you have no real guarantee of security, but one possible answer could be to seed a prng with some number and give out the first x numbers as codes. As long as x is much smaller than the total possible number of outcomes, the chance for repetition is small, and codes could be validated by re-generating the sequence (you may want to hash parts of it for speed purposes)

if you use base 62: [a-z A-Z 0-9] with 10 numbers, there are over 839 quadrillion possible outcomes. If you were to give everyone on the planet a unique code, you would have used roughly 0.0000009% of your addressable space

Comment: regenerating a million numbers to validate a certain coupon code is valid sounds far to expensive. as for your comment: i wrote in my initial question that i cant store coupon codes in a database and i meant that.

Comment: @Laures would the check be going on at a POS terminal? or would all the requests be coming in to one server? I got Python to generate 10 Million random numbers (0 thru 62**5), sort them, and check a random number for membership in about a second.

Comment: @Aaron And Python isn't exactly a fast language.  The time it takes to generate these numbers is pretty negligible. +1 for a good solution.

Comment: i tested this Approach i java using `SecureRandom` and it works. creating, encoding and validating the first 100k codes took about (every code was validated with a fresh seeded PRG) took less then 2 minutes. i did not expect it to be this fast.